# Android/Adobe air - is it possible to embed air activity into an android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, air, adobe

I am working on a live streaming (HLS) video player, however the built in android video view does not have good support for live streaming video below JellyBean 4.1/4.2, so I was looking into using adobe air to take care of the streaming video, however I have not found a way to embed an Adobe Air activity inside my Android application - I am only able to create a separate Air Mobile application that I launch from my original application! This isn't really ideal, so I was wondering if there was a way I could put them both into 1 application?

Also on a side note is there any way to pass data from an intent to adobe air? The only work around I've seen for passing Intent data is to create a url scheme intent filter and pass extra data in the url parameters as outlined [here](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/defining-custom-url-schemes-for-your-air-mobile-applications/) (again not ideal)

Answer (score 0):

It is not posible because Adobe Air is not an activity.  Adobe Air creates applications.